# How to show singe post from custom post type in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type in wordpress backend, named Demo-questions. and i had also set upped a front page, on then i am succeed to get list of all my custom posts from that type, but i need help showing only one post on a page. only one. who's permalink has been opened. for example  if i opened

http://gaincafe.com/education/?demo_questions=first-demo-question

then i only want to show the demo question custom post named first-demo-question. Advance thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

make `single-{your custompost type name}.php` it will be given top priority to render your single post of that custom post type

So in your case `single-demo-questions.php` you can copy all code from single.php to this and can modify according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

```html
// wp-content\themes\twentysixteen by default twentysixteen theme in wordpress // 
make single-{your custompost type name}.php it will be given top priority to render your single post of that custom post type.

single-page.php  change to this format single-demo.php // demo is custom post type name.

//how to get custom post type id in in single-demo.php ///

<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
 get_header(); 
?>

 
<?php 
 $Id= get_the_ID();
  $content_post = get_post($Id);
  $content = $content_post->post_content;
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
 $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_to_use->ID);
if ($post_image_id) {$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id,array(350,350));if ($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];}


?>
```

Comment: Any explanation ?

Comment: how to get any content and thumbnail  image in single custom post page from parent page  this is useful code